# Generate Sequential Passwords in C#

Tags: c#, hash, switch-statement

I have been trying to generate passwords sequentially in C# (aaaa, aaab, aaac, ... abcd, abce) for a hash cracker (for white-hat purposes). However, I'm not sure how to do that.

Right now I have a char array, the last element of which is being incremented by a switch:

```
            switch (character) {
            case ('0'):
                character = '1';
                break;
            case ('1'):
                character = '2';
                break;
            case ('2'):
                character = '3';
                break;
            case ('3'):
                character = '4';
                break;
            case ('4'):
                character = '5';
                break;
            case ('5'):
                character = '6';
                break;
            case ('6'):
                character = '7';
                break;
            case ('7'):
                character = '8';
                break;
            case ('8'):
                character = '9';
                break;
            case ('9'):
                character = 'a';
                break;
            case ('a'):
                character = 'b';
                break;
            case ('b'):
                character = 'c';
                break;
            case ('c'):
                character = 'd';
                break;
            case ('d'):
                character = 'e';
                break;
            case ('e'):
                character = 'f';
                break;
            case ('f'):
                character = 'g';
                break;
            case ('g'):
                character = 'h';
                break;
            case ('h'):
                character = 'i';
                break;
            case ('i'):
                character = 'j';
                break;
            case ('j'):
                character = 'k';
                break;
            case ('k'):
                character = 'l';
                break;
            case ('l'):
                character = 'm';
                break;
            case ('m'):
                character = 'n';
                break;
            case ('n'):
                character = 'o';
                break;
            case ('o'):
                character = 'p';
                break;
            case ('p'):
                character = 'q';
                break;
            case ('q'):
                character = 'r';
                break;
            case ('r'):
                character = 's';
                break;
            case ('s'):
                character = 't';
                break;
            case ('t'):
                character = 'u';
                break;
            case ('u'):
                character = 'v';
                break;
            case ('v'):
                character = 'w';
                break;
            case ('w'):
                character = 'x';
                break;
            case ('x'):
                character = 'y';
                break;
            case ('y'):
                character = 'z';
                break;
            case ('z'):
                character = 'A';
                break;
            case ('A'):
                character = 'B';
                break;
            case ('B'):
                character = 'C';
                break;
            case ('C'):
                character = 'D';
                break;
            case ('D'):
                character = 'E';
                break;
            case ('E'):
                character = 'F';
                break;
            case ('F'):
                character = 'G';
                break;
            case ('G'):
                character = 'H';
                break;
            case ('H'):
                character = 'I';
                break;
            case ('I'):
                character = 'J';
                break;
            case ('J'):
                character = 'K';
                break;
            case ('K'):
                character = 'L';
                break;
            case ('L'):
                character = 'M';
                break;
            case ('M'):
                character = 'N';
                break;
            case ('N'):
                character = 'O';
                break;
            case ('O'):
                character = 'P';
                break;
            case ('P'):
                character = 'Q';
                break;
            case ('Q'):
                character = 'R';
                break;
            case ('R'):
                character = 'S';
                break;
            case ('S'):
                character = 'T';
                break;
            case ('T'):
                character = 'U';
                break;
            case ('U'):
                character = 'V';
                break;
            case ('V'):
                character = 'W';
                break;
            case ('W'):
                character = 'X';
                break;
            case ('X'):
                character = 'Y';
                break;
            case ('Y'):
                character = 'Z';
                break;
            case ('Z'):
                character = '@';
                break;
            case ('@'):
                character = '%';
                break;
            case ('%'):
                character = '/';
                break;
            case ('/'):
                character = '\\';
                break;
            case ('\\'):
                character = '\'';
                break;
            case ('\''):
                character = '!';
                break;
            case ('!'):
                character = '$';
                break;
            case ('$'):
                character = '#';
                break;
            case ('#'):
                character = '^';
                break;
            case ('^'):
                character = '?';
                break;
            case ('?'):
                character = ':';
                break;
            case (':'):
                character = ',';
                break;
            case (','):
                character = '(';
                break;
            case ('('):
                character = ')';
                break;
            case (')'):
                character = '[';
                break;
            case ('['):
                character = ']';
                break;
            case (']'):
                character = '{';
                break;
            case ('{'):
                character = '}';
                break;
            case ('}'):
                character = '-';
                break;
            case ('-'):
                character = '_';
                break;
            case ('_'):
                character = '+';
                break;
            case ('+'):
                character = '=';
                break;
            case ('='):
                character = '0';
                break;
                prev = true;
            default:
                character = '0';
                break;
        }
```

However, when that element reaches 0 again, I need to increment the previous digit of the password and if that digit also reaches 0, I need to increment the *previous* digit from that one, and so on.

Also, since this is a hash cracker, it needs to be fast. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should really consider working with [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) codes instead. Just as a sidenote.

Comment: Your switch lacks `break;`s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first answer wouldn't give you quite what you want. This will:

Create a string that defines your alphabet:

```
const string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
```

Then initialize an int array with all -1, as long as your longest password. This one will do up to 8 characters:

```
int[] pwArray = new int[] {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1};
```

Then run a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Whatever; ++i)
{
    string password = ToPasswordString(pwArray, Alphabet);
    // do something with the password
}

string ToPasswordString(int[] pass, string alphabet)
{
    for (int i = pass.Length-1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        pass[i]++;
        if (pass[i] < alphabet.Length)
        {
            break;
        }
        pass[i] = 0;
    }
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < pass.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (pass[i] >= 0)
            sb.Append(alphabet[pass[i]]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

The key here is that we don't modify password characters. Rather, we modify indexes into the character array.

Granted, this won't be as fast as some other methods (passwords per second), but your program's speed is limited by how fast the site you're hacking can respond to login tries. The amount of time you spend generating passwords is irrelevant when compared to that.

Comment: I like that idea, I'll give it a try later. It's actually cracking a hash on my local machine btw.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a complicated and extremely large switch statement why not just directly map `int` values to `char`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)Char.MaxValue; i++) { 
  char c = (char)i;
  ...
}
```

This would allow you to build up brute force password generator pretty easily.

Comment: note that 0 to 256 is likely not the range you would want to use.

Comment: If this is a password cracker you likely are not wanting to test things that are not printable ASCII. A more likely range (without going in to Unicode) would be `for (int i = (int)' '; i < (int)'~'; i++)`

Comment: So you are casting an integer into a character right? Char.MaxValue is 65535, are there that many different chars or am I misunderstanding this? How do I handle the multiple digits of the password?

Comment: @Razick nested `for` loops, a loop for each digit of the password.

Comment: Don't forget another outer loop to handle password lengths.

Comment: The problem with this method is that there are 126 characters `<= '~'`, which makes cracking exponentially slower than if we limit the method to 84 characters.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain wouldn't we want to include printable unicode characters here as well?

Comment: @Razick if you don't want to do ranges don't include them, we are just trying to show you how to use a for loop instead of a switch statement, you don't need to use the max range, I was just demonstrating the max range. Jared, no we woulden't if you are brute forcing somthing doing a range that large would make such a large keyspace that it makes the attempt pointless once you get over 3 or 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ascii` code, for sample:

```
public char GetNextChar(char c)
{
   return (char)(((int)c) + 1);
}
```

Would be a nice extension, for sample:

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static char GetNextChar(this char c)
   {
      return (char)(((int)c) + 1);
   }
}
```

and using it:

```
character = character.GetNextChar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
char[] currPassword = new char[] { (char)65, (char)65, (char)65, (char)65, (char)65 }; //65 = A
const int Z = 90;
const int A = 65;

void Main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        string curr = new string(currPassword);
        Next();
    }
}

public void Next()
{
    int currIndex = currPassword.Length -1;
    bool done = false;

    do
    {
        currPassword[currIndex]++;

        if(currPassword[currIndex] > Z && currIndex >= 0) 
        {
            currPassword[currIndex] = (char)A;
            currIndex--;
        }
        else
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }while(!done);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[LINQLIB](https://linqlib.codeplex.com/) contains methods to compute all permutations or combinations.  You could use it instead although the order might not be exactly as you describe in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Another different approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string charSet = "0123456789!@#$%^&*";

            string password = "20@";
            StringBuilder start = new StringBuilder("0");
            int j = 0;
            int z = 0;
            while (start.ToString() != password)
            {
                start[z] = charSet[j++];
                Console.WriteLine(start);
                if (j == charSet.Length)
                {
                    if (start.ToString().Where(c => c == charSet[charSet.Length - 1]).Count() == start.ToString().Length)
                    {
                        start.Append("0");
                        for (int t = 0; t < start.Length; t++)
                        {
                            start[t] = '0';

                        }
                        z++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int t = start.Length - 2; t >= 0; t--)
                        {
                            if (charSet.IndexOf(start[t]) == charSet.Length - 1)
                            {
                                start[t] = '0';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                start[t] = charSet[charSet.IndexOf(start[t]) + 1];
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    j = 0;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just treat each of your password entries as numbers, its base being the number of characters present in the initial Dictionary. Whenever you reach a maximum in a given position, you 'carry over' to the next 'digit'.

This small class will return all possible combinations, given:

- an initial character dictionary
- a minimum password size
- a maximum password size

Just keep in mind that sequences like that get EXTREMELY large very fast, depending on the initial dictionary size. For example, the following code with default values (minChar=2,MaxChar=4) generates 866495 entries.

```
public class Sequencer
{
    public string characterDictionary = "0123456789";
    //public string characterDictionary = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-=[];',./`~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?|\\";
    public int minCharCount = 2;
    public int maxCharCount = 4;

    private List<string> _sequence;


    public List<string> GetSequence()
    {

        _sequence = new List<string>();


        for (int i = minCharCount; i < (maxCharCount + 1); i++)
            RenderCombinations(i);

        return _sequence;
    }

    private void RenderCombinations(int charCount)
    {
        int _dictSize = characterDictionary.Length;
        int[] _containerMatrix = new int[charCount];
        char[] _splitDict = characterDictionary.ToCharArray();

        bool _maxReached = false;

        do
        {
            string _currentCombination = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < charCount; i++)
                _currentCombination += _splitDict[_containerMatrix[i]];

            _sequence.Add(_currentCombination);

            // Let the shifting begin!

            bool _mustCarry = false;
            int _carryIndex = 0;

            do
            {
                _mustCarry = false;

                if (_carryIndex == _containerMatrix.Length)
                {
                    _maxReached = true;
                    break;
                }

                _containerMatrix[_carryIndex]++;

                if (_containerMatrix[_carryIndex] == _dictSize)
                {
                    _mustCarry = true;
                    _containerMatrix[_carryIndex] = 0;
                }

                _carryIndex++;

                if (_carryIndex > charCount)
                {
                    _mustCarry = false;
                    _maxReached = true;
                }
            } while (_mustCarry);
        } while (!_maxReached);
    }
}
```